# Use VPA to evaluate tiny probabilities

Tags: matlab, statistics, precision, probability, arbitrary-precision

For a statistics application, I need to evaluate tiny chi-square probabilities. But when this becomes smaller than matlab's double-precision limit `realmin` (around 1e-308), it returns 0.

```
x=50;
p=chi2cdf(x^2,4,'upper')
>> 0
```

All I need is to store the order of magnitude of the number and a few leading digits. I know that using `vpa` you can store tiny numbers smaller than `realmin` to arbitrary precision:

```
y = vpa('1e-5000')
>> 1.0e-5000
log10(y)
>> -5000.0
```

But this doesn't seem to work with `chi2cdf`:

```
x = vpa('50');
chi2cdf(x^2,4,'upper')
```

throws an error.

Does this mean that some matlab functions, such as `chi2cdf`, were simply not designed to work with variable-precision inputs? Is there any other way around?

Comment: [Are you trying to figure out exactly how improbable the Infinite Improbability Drive is?](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Infinite_Improbability_Drive)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Huh, the answer to you-know-what-question is hidden in the first decimals of the example code's result

Comment: @LuisMendo Indeed, it is! What’s the probability of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `chi2cdf` does not support symbolic inputs. The chi-squared distribution function [can be expressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) in terms of the regularized incomplete gamma function, which is `gammainc` in Matlab, but that one does not support symbolic inputs either.

So you may have to define the complementary distribution function manually as a symbolic integral by means of [`int`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.int.html), using only functions that accept symbolic inputs:

```
x = 50; % input value 
k = 4; % input value
d = 30; % number of digits
syms ks ts
result = int(ts^(ks/2-1)*exp(-ts/2)/2^(ks/2)/gamma(ks/2), ts, inf);
result = vpa(subs(subs(result, ts, x^2), ks, k), d)
```

gives

```
result =
1.69494234796096964467999437076e-540
```

Comment: Maybe try [`igamma`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.igamma.html) for the symbolic incomplete gamma function. Do note that `igamma` function returns the upper form (see tips at link).

Comment: Yep, the explicit integral works, but also defining the complementary CDF in terms of igamma worked: `result=vpa(igamma(sym(k/2),sym(x/2))/gamma(sym(k/2)))`

Comment: @horchler and Luis Mendo, you really helped me get unstuck, I'm putting you in the acknowledgments of this paper :)

Comment: @AbhranilDas Thank you so much! I'd love to see the draft when it's ready :-)